# Finding unique powers using prime factorization

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner trying to solve 1 problem and I can't wrap my head around this.

When I use prime factorization, it outputs different results for powers with same value.
For example:
2^4 => 2^2 2^2
4^2 => 2^4

I know it's correct factorization in both cases but I'm trying to save this into a set which will not accept these two as different.

I've been trying to solve this but I have not been able to.
Here's the function prime_factorization and unique_powers

```
vector<pair<int, int>> prime_factorization(int n) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> factors; 
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
        factors.emplace_back(2, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
            factors.emplace_back(i, 1);
        }
    }
    
    if (n > 2) {
        factors.emplace_back(n, 1);
    }
    return factors;
}

set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique_powers(int a, int b) {
    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique;

    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= b; j++) {
            vector<pair<int, int>> factors = prime_factorization(i);

            //most likely not correct compression of powers
            /*
            if (factors.size() > 1) {
                pair<int, int> new_factor = factors[0];
                new_factor.second = new_factor.second * factors.size();
                factors.clear();
                factors.push_back(new_factor);
            }
            */

            for (pair<int, int>& factor : factors) {
                factor.second *= j;
            }

            unique.insert(factors);
        }
    }

    return unique;
}
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, int>> prime_factorization(int n) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> factors; 
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
        factors.emplace_back(2, 1);
    }

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
            factors.emplace_back(i, 1);
        }
    }
    
    if (n > 2) {
        factors.emplace_back(n, 1);
    }
    return factors;
}

set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique_powers(int a, int b) {
    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique;

    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= b; j++) {
            vector<pair<int, int>> factors = prime_factorization(i);

            for (pair<int, int>& factor : factors) {
                factor.second *= j;
            }

            unique.insert(factors);
        }
    }

    return unique;
}

int main()
{
   set<vector<pair<int, int>>> s = unique_powers(5, 5);
   for (auto v : s) {
       for (auto p : v) {
           cout << p.first << "^" << p.second << "\t| ";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
   cout << "Unique powers count: " << s.size();
}
```

This is my output. It shows where my problem lies but I was unable to solve it.

```
equation a^b:
a = 5
b = 5
2^2     |
2^2     | 2^2   | <= THIS POWER
2^3     |
2^3     | 2^3   |
2^4     |     <= THIS POWER
2^4     | 2^4   |
2^5     |
2^5     | 2^5   |
3^2     |
3^3     |
3^4     |
3^5     |
5^2     |
5^3     |
5^4     |
5^5     |
Unique powers count: 16
```

Lines marked with THIS POWER are equivalent in value but their prime factorization has been saved differently, thus they were save as different numbers in a set.

The problem is that the correct answer should be 15.
This is the explanation:
I take powers of 2 up to the input number (5 in this case)
I set both a and b to 5 so the number of powers is 16 but only 15 powers are unique (because 2^4 is the same value as 4^2)

This is the correct output this program should provide:

```
equation a^b:
a = 5
b = 5
2^2     |
2^3     |
2^4     |
2^5     |
2^6     |
2^8     |
2^10    |
3^2     |
3^3     |
3^4     |
3^5     |
5^2     |
5^3     |
5^4     |
5^5     |
Unique powers count: 15
```

SOLVED - Code for people who might encounter the same problem in future:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

vector<pair<int, int>> prime_factorization(int n) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> factors; 

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
        factors.emplace_back(2, 1);
        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
            factors.back().second += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            factors.emplace_back(i, 1);
            while (n % i == 0) {
                n /= i;
                factors.back().second += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (n > 2) {
        factors.emplace_back(n, 1);
    }
    return factors;
}

set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique_powers(int a, int b) {
    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> unique;

    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= b; j++) {
            vector<pair<int, int>> factors = prime_factorization(i);

            for (pair<int, int>& factor : factors) {
                factor.second *= j;
            }

            unique.insert(factors);
        }
    }

    return unique;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> s1 = unique_powers(5, 5);
    cout << "Unique powers: " << s1.size() << endl;

    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> s2 = unique_powers(100, 100);
    cout << "Unique powers: " << s2.size() << endl;

    set<vector<pair<int, int>>> s3 = unique_powers(1000, 1000);
    cout << "Unique powers: " << s3.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What are you trying to do? I see an image which is supposed to show that something doesn't work correctly. I don't see anything wrong in the image. So, what is the problem? What would you like to see in your image when the problem is solved? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: "trying to solve 1 problem" What problem? I re-read your question several times and I still don't get it. It looks like it has something to do with "unique_powers" which seems to be a function of 2 variables. How is it defined?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the concept of a [mre], though you appreciatedly tried to provide one. Please read the information linked and try again. An MRE should be a full program that can be built and run to demosntrate the obersved problem, ideally without need for manual input. Please also provide the expected ouput in contrast to the output you get, as text instead of as picture of text. Consider extending the output to make it more selfexplaining.

Comment: You might get things to behave more reliably if you only use primes to decompose your composite number into. Things will get even more tricky when you go past 9 since that is also composite and will show similar misbehaviour. I'm not sure I understand the definition of your problem though. Why isn't eg 7^2 11^2  a valid solution? Is the original question how many numbers of the form a^b  are unique? (for a,b<=5) . If it is there are much neater ways to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your prime factorization function.

```
while (n % 2 == 0) {
    n /= 2;
    factors.emplace_back(2, 1);
}
```

The pairs in your `factors` vector specify a prime number and its power. What happens if your input can be divided by 2 several times? Your code records several pairs `(2, 1)`. Not good! You need just one pair `(2, n)`.

To accomplish that, your code should do either of two possible things:

- Is the last pair `(2, n)`? If yes, increase `n`.
- Otherwise? Insert `(2, 1)`.

The same for all other primes.

You can implement this by checking the last pair, but maybe better by splitting your insertion code into two parts, one after the other.

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    n /= 2;
    factors.emplace_back(2, 1);
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        n /= 2;
        factors.back().second += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the reason why my program is not working as intended.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

When you factorize a number into its prime factors, you express it as the product of prime numbers. The prime factorization of 2^4, for example, is 2 * 2 * 2 * 2, or simply written as 2^4. It's not broken down into 2^2 * 2^2 or anything like that.

Let me show you the correct prime factorization for 2^4:

## 2
4

2
∗
2
∗
2
∗
2
2
4
=2∗2∗2∗2

If you're trying to represent 2^4 as a product of smaller powers of 2, you would write it as:

## 2
4

## 2
2
∗
2
2
2
4

2
∗2
2